# How to differ between external HDD and internal ones?

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, sata

I want to know whether device is connected via USB (meaning it is a removable hard drive) or SATA (meaning it is an internal hard drive).
That is how I get a list of devices

```
SP_DEVINFO_DATA volumeData;
volumeData.cbSize = sizeof (SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA volumeInterfaceData;
volumeInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
wchar_t buffer[1024];
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA volumeInterfaceDetail;
volumeInterfaceDetail = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)buffer;
volumeInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
for (int j = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces (hVolumeInfo, 0, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME, j, &volumeInterfaceData); j++) {
    DWORD bufferPathSize = offsetof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, DevicePath) + sizeof(TCHAR);
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (
        hVolumeInfo,
        &volumeInterfaceData,
        volumeInterfaceDetail,
        bufferPathSize,
        &bufferPathSize,
        &volumeData
        ));
    <some actions here>
}
```

After such operations I get a kind of the following result for each connected volume:

```
volumeInterfaceDetail->DevicePath: "\\\\?\\storage#volume#{3ec3ba03-2789-11e4-8251-806e6f6e6963}#0000000015f00000#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}"
```

How can I detect an interface (USB, SATA) with which the considering device is connected? Or is there any other way to differ external and internal HDDs using WinAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Use [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get a handle on to the device.
2. Use [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send an [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ioctl to the device to ask it to tell you its properties.
3. The resulting [`STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure contains a [`BusType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumeration that tells you the bus to which it is attached.

There's a small code snippet at the bottom of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that you can use to get started.

Comment: I don't see any code snippets in the last page you linked (except for a single function call).  However, I did find [this helpful example](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/10/26/get-physical-drive-serial-number-part-1/).

Comment: You're right @Jeff Irwin, Microsoft have edited the page and removed the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`GetDriveType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just the thing to establish the drive type.

---

If you're really interested in USB versus non-USB instead of whether the drive is removable, then the documentation of `GetDriveType` states, up-front:

> **”** To determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, call `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` and specify the `SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY` property.